# SQL Server : how to perform a semi-Join without using dot notation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a statement in the following manner:

```
select attrib1, attrib2, attrib3, ...
from   table
where exists (
     select attrib1, attrib2 as foo, attrib3, ...
     from   table
     where  foo < attrib2
)
```

So, I'm not allowed to use dot notation. Is this even possible?

EDIT:
The query I described is similar to a semi-join in relational algebra. I want to rename the column `attrib2` to `foo` and select each column from `table` with `foo < attrib2`.

Comment: What do you mean you're not allowed to use dot notation?

Comment: Unusual to select specific columns within an `EXISTS`.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a correlated subquery without referencing an alias?

Comment: Is this question about MySQL or SQL Server? You've tagged it for both (and tags should usually not be used in question titles, by the way).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the ellipses in the query?  If so, that is not part of standard SQL.  The correct form of your query would be:

```
select t.*
from   table t
where exists (
     select 1
     from   table t2
     where  t2.attrib2 < t.attrib2
)
```

Although you should see sgeddes's answer for an alternative formulation.

Comment: +1 Rereading the question, this very well could be what the OP is after.  Dot Notation -- come on, more details!

Comment: Select * should never be used in production code, He should list every column he needs and only those he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to "dot notation": do you mean not to reference the tables?  If so, why?

For this specific query, I do believe it can be rewritten to just use a subquery with `MAX`:

```
SELECT attrib1, attrib2
FROM table1 
WHERE attrib2 < (select max(attrib2) from table1)
```

Considering what the `EXISTS` is accomplishing, it's returning all records except those with the highest attrib2.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb19b/3)